# Git hard reset to current branch -> destroying installed components?

Tags: git, bower, git-reset

When I install a package via bower, and do a hard reset to a commit then, will the installed package be removed as well?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: Why are you adding a bower component to the git repo? You should have `bower_components` in your `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are not tracked then they will remain in the working copy. If your plan is to get rid of them you can use:`git clean -f -d`